# unable to show the last item in the stack pop ()

Tags: c#, winforms, stack

I'm implementing backword function on a button. that when clicked moves to the previous link in the stack. the problem is this if it has one element in the stack pop() it gives an error of stack empty.

```
 private void Backward_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
try
{
if (simpleStack.Count != 0)
{
simpleStack.Pop();
string open = simpleStack.Pop();

PopulateListView(open);

complicatedStack.Push(open);

}

else if (simpleStack.Count == 0)
{
Backward.Enabled = false;

}
```

It works when I have more than one clicks n goes back to the previous item selected.but does not show the last one.  I'm passing string in simpleStack. can anybody tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at your code:

```
simpleStack.Pop();
string open = simpleStack.Pop();
```

You're popping twice, and ignoring the first result. Why would you do that? I suspect you can just remove the first `Pop` call.

Also note that your `else` clause doesn't need to check `simpleStack.Count == 0` - it must be, otherwise you wouldn't be evaluating the `else` clause. (Unless you've got multiple threads doing stuff of course - which wouldn't be a good idea.)

Comment: plz see the above comments for that line..the issue is this that when i push the path of the directories i brose in a stack.....i need to show the base item of stack also..and simplestack.pop when called first removes only item at the top then it comes to the next statement ....

Comment: i need to put some kind of condition on removing the top element ...i guess

Comment: @engineer41: There are no comments anywhere in the code you've posted. There are a couple of (somewhat confusing) statements before and after... but it's fundamentally unclear why you'd want to pop twice. That *will* fail when there's only one element though, for hopefully obvious reasons.

Comment: after removing the else condition and the simplestack.pop it works fine...but now it shows the current path again which looks very stupid when i press the back button...showing the same folder again...how can i remove the top element

Comment: okw just explain me why it wont work when there is one element in stack?

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
private void Backward_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (simpleStack.Count != 0)
            {
                //simpleStack.Pop();    // Remove this line
                string open = simpleStack.Pop();

                PopulateListView(open);

                complicatedStack.Push(open);

            }
            else if (simpleStack.Count == 0)
            {
                Backward.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: no it dont work this way...as then the directory(path) i am on currently is repeated and then it moves back to previous path and then not showing the last path(from where i started) it disables the button

Comment: i was using that line because i wanted to remove the top most element of the stack and then throw it nowhere...simapleStack.pop do that.but ok if i remove it it still miss the element that is all the base of stack..:(plz help